# For any set $A⊆R$, $\exists$ a $σ$-algebra $Σ$ of subsets of $\mathbb R$ s.t. $A \notin \Sigma$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is this true or false?

I think it is false because from the sigma algebra of $X$ definition, we know that if $E\in \Sigma$ then $X \setminus E \in \Sigma$.

But this means that if $A \notin \Sigma \implies \mathbb R \setminus A \notin \Sigma$ then something further which I cant think of...

Comment: There are three cases you should think about: (i) $A=\Bbb R$. (ii) $A=\emptyset$. (iii) Everything else.

Comment: $\{\emptyset,\,\Bbb R\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Maybe two more conditions should be added to this question: (iii) $A$ is a nonempty proper subset of $\Bbb R$. (iv) $\Sigma \ne \{\varnothing,\Bbb R\}$  Otherwise, as William Krinsman points out, the question is trivial.

Comment: The statement is obviouly false, since $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$  are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$  and they are in every $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Even if we add (iii) $A$ is a nonempty proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and  (iv) $\Sigma \neq \{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}$ (as suggested by @GNUSupporter), the question remains trivial. It becomes trivially true. Let $B$ be a nonempty proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$  such that $B\neq A$.  Then $\Sigma = \{\emptyset, B, B^c,  \mathbb{R}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$ and $A\notin \Sigma$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's false because the empty set and R are always in any sigma algebra on R.

Comment: I don't understand... so what if the empty set and R are in the sig algebra of R???

Comment: youre saying it would be false if we took A to equal empty set or R?

Comment: The statement says, for ANY subset of R, this holds. But R and the empty set are subsets of R for which the statement does not hold. Hence the statement is false.

Comment: Obviously of course the question is much more interesting for any other subsets, but technically if one does not exclude the empty set and R, the statement is trivially false.

Comment: Actually, even for the other subsets the question remains trivial. It is then trivially true. Suppose $A$ is a nonempty proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then, $\Sigma_1 \neq \{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $A\notin \Sigma_1$. Also, let $B$ be a nonempty proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$  such that $B\neq A$.  Then $\Sigma_2 = \{\emptyset, B, B^c,  \mathbb{R}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$ and $A\notin \Sigma_2$.